# Not able to get formated_address 'only in English' getting some part of result in regional language

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-apis-explorer

I'm getting some part of google map result in regional language need complete result in ENGLISH

I have tried hitting map's API with changing the language to `'en'` and region to `'IN'`

```
$geocode=file_get_contents(https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=12.9415554,77.5595728&sensor=false&key=MYAPIGOOGLEKRY&language=en&region=IN);
        $geocode_arr=json_decode($geocode,true);
        if(array_key_exists("0",$geocode_arr['results'])){
        $arr_exp=explode(",",$geocode_arr['results'][0]['formatted_address']);
        $arr_exp=array_slice($arr_exp, -4, 3, true);
        $address_str=implode(",",$arr_exp);
        print_r($address_str); exit;
        }
```

Getting result :

```
ಬನಶಂಕರಿ, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560050 
('ಬನಶಂಕರಿ' regional language)
```

Expected Result :

```
XYZ, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560050
```

Comment: Try with not giving the region in query string

Comment: Tried same still getting regional language
ಬನಶಂಕರಿ, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560050

Comment: Then do you require the whole address otherwise you can go with city and country as well?

Comment: need complete address

Comment: try with `$geocode_arr['results'][1]['formatted_address']`

Comment: for this latitude longitude, it will work but not sure if it will break for another latitude longitude

Comment: I think you will always get these 0 and 1 both result in anyways 
or you can simply check if 1 is not set then go for zero

Comment: yes I can do that but is there a way that API can give us formatted address only in ENGLISH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intended behavior from the Maps APIs. At this time it's not possible to return `formatted_address` in English only. Refer to [Google's post](https://mapsplatform.googleblog.com/2014/11/localization-of-street-addresses-in.html) on Localization of Street Addresses in the Google Maps APIs.

> Street-level addresses returned by the Google Maps Geocoding API now
>   favor the local language, while keeping the address understandable as
>   much as possible for both a user who only reads the requested language
>   as well as locals.
>
> If the local language and user language both use the same alphabet,
>   the Geocoding API will now return the local names for the streets and
>   localities. For example, searching for an address in Brazil with user
>   language set to English now returns “Avenida Paulista” rather than
>   “Paulista Avenue”.

So this example request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Avenida+Paulista,+Bela+Vista&key=KEY
```

returns this:

```
formatted_address: "Av. Paulista - Bela Vista, São Paulo - SP, Brazil"
```

The [Geocoding documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#geocoding) also mentions this:

> The geocoder does its best to provide a street address that is
>   readable for both the user and locals. To achieve that goal, it
>   returns street addresses in the local language, transliterated to a
>   script readable by the user if necessary, observing the preferred
>   language. All other addresses are returned in the preferred language.
>   Address components are all returned in the same language, which is
>   chosen from the first component.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you! Happy to help :)