# How to get the formatted address in english using google map API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I try to query Google API using below URL
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Gustaf dalengatan 5, goteberg, Swe&language=en_AU&key=

It returns the address with Swedish characters even though I have specified language as english.
How to force Google API to return the address in English.

I get formatted address as 
"formatted_address" : "Gustaf Dalénsgatan, Göteborg, Sweden"

But I need it to be in english
"formatted_address" : "Gustaf Dalensgatan, Gotheberg, Sweden"

Regards
Yogesh

Comment: 1) *Gotheberg* is **not** the English translation of *Göteborg* 2) The country code you are using is wrong 3) The language code you are using is wrong 4) The documentation which you obviously haven't read mentions other points which explain why you don't get *Göteborg* translated with the request you shared.

Comment: can you share the link of documentation

Comment: Please check out my answer in related thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/57754716/11742502